# Differential Equation using change of variables $(xy+2xy(\ln y)^2+y\ln y)\mathrm{d}x+(2x^2\ln y+x)\mathrm{d}y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, change-of-variable

Solve this differential equation using given change of variables $(xy+2xy(\ln y)^2+y\ln y)\mathrm{d}x+(2x^2\ln y+x)\mathrm{d}y=0$ , change of variable $t=x\ln y$

I get that:
$t' = \mathrm{d}t/\mathrm{d}x = \ln y + \frac{x}{y}y'$

$$\begin{align}
-(2x^2\ln y+x)y' &= xy +2xy(\ln y)^2 + y \ln y \\
-(2x^2\ln y /y + x/y)y' &= x + 2x(\ln y)^2 + \ln y \\
-(2tx/y)y' &= x + 2x(\ln y)^2 + \ln y + y' x/y \\
-(2tx/y)y' &= x + 2t \ln y + t' \\
-(2t)(x/y) y' &= x +2t \ln y + t' \\
-(2t) (t' - \ln y) &= x + 2t \ln y + t'
\end{align}$$
But it didn't get to something good to be easily integrable. Note that this question is asked for First-order Ordinary Differential Equation. So it probably shouldn't get very complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just stopped too soon:
$$\begin{aligned}
-(2t)(t'-\ln y)&=x+2t\ln y+t'\\
-2tt'+2t\ln y&=x+2t\ln y+t'\\
-2tt'&=x+t'.
\end{aligned}$$